# CComboBox only accept number in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to create a combo box in MFC /VC++ in which user can enter or select values in between 0 to 9999 only.
How can I acheive this functionality.

Please Help

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
CComboBox* pCombo = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1);

CWnd* pComboEdit = pCombo->GetWindow(GW_CHILD);

if (pComboEdit != NULL)
    pComboEdit->ModifyStyle(0, ES_NUMBER);
```

---

**Edit:** In order to restrict the number of characters/digits:

```
((CEdit*)pComboEdit)->LimitText(4);
```

Comment: its good. but i want to restrict to enter upto 4 character.
i.e. 0 to 9999

Comment: Perfect solution what I want. Thanks

Comment: Or you can use: `CEdit* pEdit = pCombo->GetDlgItem(1001);`

Answer (score -2):

CComboBox* pCombo = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDS_COMBO1);

for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
 pCombo->AddString(CString::Format(_T("%d"),i);